# AddThis Facebook share button with popup

Tags: facebook, popup, share, addthis

I am trying to use AddThis for a Facebook and Twitter share button like this:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_16x16_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
...

<script type="text/javascript">
  var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
  addthis_config.data_track_addressbar = false;
  addthis_config.data_track_clickback = false;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-516a8c1a380e068d"></script>
```

(of course i also include the AddThis JavaScript.)

The Twitter button opens a popup but the Facebook button opens in a new browser tab. Why does this happen? I need the Facebook share function to open in a popup too. A fullscreen tab just looks wrong and ugly.

Comment: Well, clearly the difference is in the Javascript so the fact that you haven't posted it is unhelpful!

Comment: I have added it now but it just is the Addthis include line. I don't do anything special there.

Comment: Should it not be `src="http://..."` in that second script tag?

Comment: No, this seems to be a standard JavaScript practice to have http or https autoselected?

Comment: Oh right, well I learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/921191-facebook-share-dialog-opens-in-new-tab-rather-than-popup

There's your answer. That's the default, and only, behaviour available!

Comment: I have already seen this but I couldn't believe it so I asked here. :) It's useless this way... This bug seems to exist for many months and many people complained. They just would have to call window.open() in their JavaScript. :( I tried to use my own click event with JQuery but I didn't succeed with disabling theirs. (For the other buttons i still would like to use AddThis if possible.)

Comment: Okay, well, I can't help you with editing their code and it's a bit of a long shot but good luck!